# how to remove elements of array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is it possible to remove the contents of the array based on the index? If I have 2 arrays like these:

Array1 that contains 15 values and I want to get the last 10 values.

Before removing elements:

```
array1 == [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]
```

After removing elements:

```
array1 == [5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]
```

Array2 that contains 15 values and then I want to get only the first 10 values.

Before removing elements:

```
array2 == [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]
```

After removing elements:

```
array2 == [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

But there are conditions that must be fulfilled:

if the array only contains 3 elements is not necessary to discard the elements in the array, as well as if the array contains 10 elements only. but if the array contains more than 10 elements, the excess is discarded.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

To keep the first ten items:

```
if (theArray.length > 10) theArray = theArray.slice(0, 10);
```

or, perhaps less intuitive:

```
if (theArray.length > 10) theArray.length = 10;
```

To keep the last ten items:

```
if (theArray.length > 10) theArray = theArray.slice(theArray.length - 10, 10);
```

You can use a negative value for the first parameter to specify length - n, and omitting the second parameter gets all items to the end, so the same can also be written as:

```
if (theArray.length > 10) theArray = theArray.slice(-10);
```

The `splice` method is used to remove items and replace with other items, but if you specify no new items it can be used to only remove items. To keep the first ten items:

```
if (theArray.length > 10) theArray.splice(10, theArray.length - 10);
```

To keep the last ten items:

```
if (theArray.length > 10) theArray.splice(0, theArray.length - 10);
```

Comment: just keep in mind, splice will edit original array too, while slice - not.

Comment: @LukasLiesis This has always annoyed me because it feels like an inconsistency. If anyone knows why this is, I'd love to know!

Comment: To keep last N items you can also reverse set length and then reverse back (or keep it if you don't care about the sequence)

Answer (score 18):

Use the function `array.splice(index, count)` to remove `count` elements at `index`. To remove elements from the end, use `array1.splice(array1.length - 10, 1);`

Comment: hmm i don't know what do you mean with index and count,can you explain it?

Comment: @user495688 index shows where to start to remove items and count - how many items to remove. e.g. array.splice(0, 5) removes 5 items starting with index 0. In other words - from beginning.

Answer (score 5):

See [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

> The `splice()` method changes the content of an array by removing existing elements and/or adding new elements.

It won't create a new array, if you want to create new array use `slice`.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but it did create a new array for me (and mutated the existing array). e.g. `var b = a.splice(0, 3)`

Answer (score 4):

Kind of hard to follow your question, but try these:

```
array = array.slice(-10);

// or

last10 = array.splice(-10);
// array has first array.length-10 elements
```